How do I align a LaTeX equation left when the document in in Hebrew?
I am trying to do an assignment in Hebrew in LaTeX. So far, I have written the following:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[א)]
    $$\begin{aligned}
    (4-9i)(-2-5i)&=4\cdot(-2)+4\cdot(-5i)+(-9i)\cdot(-2)+(-9i)\cdot(-5i)\\
    &=-8-20i+18i+45i^2\\
    &=-8-45-20i+18i\\
    &=-53-2i
    \end{aligned}$$
    תשובה:
    $-53-2i$.
    \item[ב)]
    $$\begin{aligned}
    (7-i)^3&=(7-i)(7-i)(7-i)\\
    &=(49-7i-7i+i^2)(7-i)\\
    &=(48-14i)(7-i)\\
    &=48\cdot7-14i\cdot7-48i+14i^2\\
    &=336-14-98i-48i\\
    &=322-146i
    \end{aligned}$$
    תשובה:
    $322-146i$.
\end{enumerate}

However, the equations are centered and I want them aligned to the left.
I have tried using the flalign* environment, but due to the document being in Hebrew, this aligns the equation to the right, not to the left. I have also tried changing the document language after the \item command using \selectlanguage{english}, but that makes the result of the \item[א)] command displayed on the left too, which I don't want.
EDIT: I am using LuaLaTeX, but can switch to XeLaTeX if necessary. Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}[Script=Hebrew]{Hadasim CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfonttt}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[א)]
    $$\begin{aligned}
    a&=b\\
    &=c
    \end{aligned}$$
    תשובה:
    $c$.
    \item[ב)]
    $$\begin{aligned}
    a&=b\\
    &=c
    \end{aligned}$$
    תשובה:
    $c$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

I am still trying to figure out how polyglossia works, so feel free to suggest changes in the preamble. But I don't want to switch to something different from polyglossia because the Hebrew font IMO looks ugly without it.

pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex? babel, polyglossia, cjhebrew? Please, provide a MWE.

even without the Hebrew complication $$ is unsupported in latex, precisely because it does not obey alignment options such as [fleqn] for flush left rather than centred display math see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

@JavierBezos updated the question.

@DmitryVolovich The font has no relation with the multilingual package used. With both babel and polyglossia you can choose the font you want. The bidi support in polyglossia for luatex is limited: I would recommend either polyglossia+xetex (if you want to stick to polyglossia) or babel+luatex.
